# Web Api Response

Tags: c#, api

While testing my API in Browser,  only the Get method is called.

When I browse http://localhost:xxxxx/api/student/GetStudentById/38
I get the correct value from Database.
Here GetStudentById is the [ActionName] under [HttpGet].

But when I browse http://localhost:xxxxx/api/student/StudentDeleteById/38
I get "The requested resource does not support http method 'GET'."
**(Why it is getting Redirected to Get)?**
Here StudentDeleteById is the [ActionName] under [HttpDelete].

I have tested my API in Postman every Request is executing successfully(i.e Get, Put, Post, Delete)

Below is my WebApiConfig.cs

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
```

Comment: because if you execute the method in the browser you actually do a get request and not a delete request, but your action is taged with httpdelete, and thats why it gets ignored, and you get an error

Answer (score 1):

Browser sends only GET requests when you type URL in the address bar. 
In order to send DELETE request, you can use curl command-line util

```
curl -X "DELETE"  http://localhost:xxxxx/api/student/StudentDeleteById/38
```

or create small page with jQuery which sends request:

```
function sendDelete() {
  $.ajax( 
  {
    url: 'http://localhost/api/student/StudentDeleteById/38',
    method: 'DELETE'
  }).done(function () {
    alert('done');
  });
```

}